# Advantages of splitting a single NMOS transistor into two

Tags: mosfet, bias

Can anybody explain to me why in the schematic attached below that using two transistors is better than using only one transistor that is larger (longer)?

I see that these two transistors are the equivalent of one with length = L30+L31, so but why can't we use one transistor that is longer? I think that using two gives you bigger input resistance, but is this the only advantage?

[image]

Comment: Where is the input, where is the output?

Comment: we have ideal current source between Vdd and M31 and we get the output current from this node. I forgot the  ideal current source

Comment: Contrary to how this Question is marked to be closed as being "unclear" this is a very clear and good question.

Comment: @Andyaka the OP is just showing a quick drawing of what he meant for clarity reasons, it's not meant to be an actual circuit, he is focusing in on "why put two transistors when you can put in one longer one"

Comment: So the "ideal current source between Vdd and M31" is applied to the gates of both MOSFETs too, or is that blue line not intended to be there?

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to several aspects of transistor design (implants, process , manufacturing sequence etc.) and how the transistor characteristics change with size.

- Threshold is not constant with gate length

  - for "analog" transistors threshold voltage shifts upwards with length
  - For "pocket" or Halo implanted transistors the threshold peaks at the minimum gate length and decreases for longer gate lengths
- For layout reasons:

  - often for matching reasons it is best to place multiple shorter length transistors in a grid and then wire them up as you see fit, rather then just making one big one,
  - this also increases yield as the pattern density on die does not change too much
- another alternative is that the designer maybe be playing with back gate effects (AKA bulk) connection and how that modulates the threshold.  Particularly in a PMOS where the NWell is not tied to the substrate.

Answer (score 0):

It's also used for compensation where the mosfet in the triode region is modeled as low impedance which indirectly feeds back the output of a two or more stage amplifier. [more on this technique is here](https://wordpress.nmsu.edu/pfurth/files/2018/01/Split_Tran_Model_MWSCAS_2017.pdf)